# Room query with math functions only works when original value is 0

Tags: android, database, math, numbers, android-room

Building up a database full of data on Android Studio, with Java and Room (not kotlin). Some are columns are text, some are numbers with decimals. However, all columns are identified as text but the first one (id, primary key).

The user writes a value (sphecornea) and submits... the app should return all lines that match that value.

**Algorithm.java** includes this function

```
 public void cnvalgorithm (View view) {
        EditText sphecornea = findViewById(R.id.sphecornea);
        String sphecorneastr = sphecornea.getText().toString();
                AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(() -> {
                  final List<Person> persons = mDb.personDao().loadPersonByAbe(sphecorneastr);
            runOnUiThread(() -> mAdapter.setTasks(persons));
        });
    }
```

**PersonDao**

```
@Query("SELECT id,firm,model,aberration_correction FROM PERSON" + " WHERE aberration_correction = :sphecorneastr")
public List<Person> loadPersonByAbe(String sphecorneastr);
```

As is, I only get the proper results when the entered value is 0. Results are empty for any other number.
I figured that the system is not recognizing "-0.20" as a number, so I tried to manipulate it as Double by changing both the Dao and Algorithm.java section. Then, I don't get any results at all.

Update:

I just realised that the app doesn't consider the data (other than 0) as numbers. I tried this code (very inelegant, I know). It adds the 0+1, but it crashes when dealing with any other number...

```
Double aberration_correctiondou = Double.parseDouble(mPersonList.get(i).getAberration_correction());
Double aberration_correctiondou2 = aberration_correctiondou + 1;
        myViewHolder.aberration_correction.setText(String.valueOf(aberration_correctiondou2));
```

update 2:

**Entity**

For the sake of your mental health, I removed many lines (more columns of the db) of the entity file.

```
@Entity(tableName = "person")
public class Person {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;
    public String firm;
    public String model;
    public String aberration_correction;
    

    @Ignore
    public Person(String    firm    ,     String    model   ,
                  String    aberration_correction   ,
                   {
        this.   firm    =   firm    ;
        this.   model   =   model   ;
        this.   aberration_correction   =   aberration_correction   ;
        
    }

    public Person(int id, String    firm    ,
                  String    model   ,
                  String    aberration_correction   ,
                  
                  ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.   firm    =   firm    ;
        this.   model   =   model   ;
        this.   aberration_correction   =   aberration_correction   ;
        
    }

    public static final String[] PERSONS = {

    };

    public Person() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirm   () {return  firm    ;} public void setFirm  (String     firm    ){this. firm    =   firm    ;}
    public String getModel  () {return  model   ;} public void setModel (String     model   ){this. model   =   model   ;}
    public String getAberration_correction  () {return  aberration_correction   ;} public void setAberration_correction (String     aberration_correction   ){this. aberration_correction   =   aberration_correction   ;}
    
}
```

A snapshot of the database:
[seems like I don't have enough points to upload images, a link is provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCUgk.jpg)

**Solution**: As proposed by @MikeT, decimals at the database should be separated by "." instead of ",".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@Query("SELECT id,firm,model,aberration_correction FROM PERSON" + " WHERE round(CAST(aberration_correction AS REAL),2) = round(CAST(:sphecorneastr AS REAL),2)"
```

or :-

```
@Query("SELECT id,firm,model,aberration_correction FROM PERSON" + " WHERE round(aberration_correction,2) = round(:sphecorneastr,2)")
```

This should convert the string literal (as Room will wrap the value in single quotes so '-0.2').

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr
See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round

Double's are stored to a very high precision and, for example -0.20 will not be stored as such, instead it will be stored as something like -0.20000000000000093 ( or -0.19500000000000092).

**Demo**

Perhaps consider this example/demo:-

First the **Person** class:-

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id=null;
    String firm;
    String model;
    String aberration_correction;
    double aberration_correction_double;

    Person(){}
    @Ignore
    Person(Long id,String firm, String model, double aberration_correction) {
        this.id  = id;
        this.firm = firm;
        this.model = model;
        this.aberration_correction = String.valueOf(aberration_correction);
        this.aberration_correction_double = aberration_correction;
    }
    @Ignore
    Person(String firm, String model, double aberration_correction) {
        this.id = null;
        this.firm = firm;
        this.model = model;
        this.aberration_correction = String.valueOf(aberration_correction);
        this.aberration_correction_double = aberration_correction;
    }
}
```

- note that the correction has both a double and a String representation (both based upon a double)

The `@Dao` annotated abstract class (could be an interface) **PersonDao**:-

```
@Dao
abstract class PersonDao {
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   abstract long insert(Person person);
   @Query("SELECT id,firm,model,aberration_correction, aberration_correction_double FROM PERSON" + " WHERE round(CAST(aberration_correction AS REAL),2) = round(CAST(:sphecorneastr AS REAL),2)")
   abstract List<Person> getPeopleByCorrection(String sphecorneastr);
   @Query("SELECT id,firm,model,aberration_correction, aberration_correction_double FROM PERSON" + " WHERE round(aberration_correction,2) = round(:sphecorneastr,2)")
   abstract List<Person> getPeopleByCorrectionV2(String sphecorneastr);
}
```

Using a basic `@Database` annotated class with `.allowMainThreadQueries` (for convenience and brevity) and with the following code in an Activity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    PersonDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getPersonDao();

        Double correction = 1.0;
        for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            dao.insert(new Person("Firm" + i,"Model" + i,correction));
            correction = correction - 0.005;
        }

        correction = -0.20;
        for (Person p: dao.getPeopleByCorrection(correction.toString())) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Firm is " + p.firm + " Model is " + p.model + " C1 is " + p.aberration_correction + " C2 is " + p.aberration_correction_double);
        }
        for (Person p: dao.getPeopleByCorrectionV2(correction.toString())) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Firm is " + p.firm + " Model is " + p.model + " C1 is " + p.aberration_correction + " C2 is " + p.aberration_correction_double);
        }
    }
}
```

1000 rows will be inserted with corrections values from 1.0 to close to - 4.0, decreasing by 0.005 (thus covering the -0.20 value).

Then both queries are used, showing no need for the CAST, but a need for the round.

When run (only designed to run the once) then the Log includes:-

```
2022-09-25 07:27:42.838 D/DBINFO: Firm is Firm239 Model is Model239 C1 is -0.19500000000000092 C2 is -0.19500000000000092
2022-09-25 07:27:42.839 D/DBINFO: Firm is Firm240 Model is Model240 C1 is -0.20000000000000093 C2 is -0.20000000000000093


2022-09-25 07:27:42.841 D/DBINFO: Firm is Firm239 Model is Model239 C1 is -0.19500000000000092 C2 is -0.19500000000000092
2022-09-25 07:27:42.841 D/DBINFO: Firm is Firm240 Model is Model240 C1 is -0.20000000000000093 C2 is -0.20000000000000093
```

As can be seen in either case that -0.20 is not a stored value but by rounding to 2 dp then close values are obtained. You may have to adjust the rounding to suit.

Looking at the actual data stored, Via App Inspection, then

The initial rows are:-

[image: ![enter image description here]

The last rows are :-

[image]

And rows around the -0.20 mark are :-

[image]

- with the extracted rows highlighted

**Additional** *(after entity and actual data provided)*

**Issue 1.**

The entity indicates that you should be using the **`aberration_correction_double`** column for the WHERE clause, not the aberration_correction column (the latter appears to only be storing  0 or 1, perhaps representing a boolean)

**Issue 2.**

The screen shot shows `,`s in the double, where you would expect a period. e.g. `-0,20` instead of expected `-0.20`. SQLite will , if asked for a REAL (double), return a 0 (hence why 0 locates all).

Not sure how the `,` got into the data but that's the issue. A get around could be to use:-

```
@Query("SELECT id,firm,model,aberration_correction_double FROM PERSON" + " WHERE round(CAST(replace(aberration_correction_double,',','') AS REAL),2) = round(CAST(replace(:sphecorneastr,',','') AS REAL),2);"
```

- probably over the top as you probably only need the first replace.

You may wish to consider updating the underlying data e.g. a one off run of:-

```
@Query("UPDATE PERSON SET aberration_correction_double = CAST(replace(aberration_correction_double,',','') AS REAL), aberration_correction = CAST(replace(aberration_correction_double,',','') AS TEXT) WHERE instr(aberration_correction_double,',');"
```

- this assumes that both columns should contain the same value.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. Still getting the same result, only when a value of 0 is entered, the function works. Any other number, such as 0.20, -0.20, -0.18... won't match. And the db is loaded with them.
Whenever I make a query "show all data", they load up. But it's the matching query that doesn't work...

Comment: @AlexT changed to round to 2 dp. If that doesn't work then edit your question and include **1)** the `@Entity` annotated class for the person table and **2)** example actual data (you can use App Inspection to view the database, you can also run queries against the actual data from within App Inspection).

Comment: @AlexT answer updated to include a demo.

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to make it work. I've tried your solution... now all results show up when a 0 is used (even the -0,2 and such) but none is shown with any other number.

I'll update the opening post with the @entity and actual data.

Comment: @AlexT updated the answer. Two issues, the 2 columns and the use of the comma instead of period.

Comment: I forgot to enlarge the column names, one of them is aberration_known (which is boolean indeed) and the other is aberration_correction (which is the -0,15 and such)...
I used a program called DB Browser to generate the database... I'll see if I can change from . to , everywhere.

Comment: Ok, those damned "," were the source of all my headaches. For some reason, all the data is included in that format. I remember testing it with "." symbols and failing... something must have been wrong when I tested it. Thank you for everything!!!